# best method and data structure for sorting a list of tuples into multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Let's say I have a list of tuples like this:

```
l = [('music','300','url'),('movie','400','url'),
('clothing','250','url'),('music','350','url'),
('music','400','url'),('movie','1000','url')]
```

and that I want to sort these tuples into multiple lists, each grouped by the first element in the tuples.  Further, once grouped into those lists, I want the new lists reverse sorted by the second element (the int).  So, the result would be:

```
music = [('music','400','url'),('music','350','url'),('music','300','url')]
movie = [('movie','1000','url'),('movie','400','url')]
clothing = [('clothing','250','url')]
```

Perhaps I could forego the multiple lists and make a list of lists of tuples?  So, I would get:

```
sortedlist = [[('music','400','url'),('music','350','url'),('music','300','url')],
[('movie','1000','url'),('movie','400','url')],
[('clothing','250','url')]]
```

But even in this case, how would I get the internal lists reverse sorted by the second element?

If I'm going about this the wrong way, please mention it.  I'm still new at Python.  Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get your lists easily with a list comprehension:

```
music = [x for x in l if x[0] == 'music']
movie = [x for x in l if x[0] == 'movie']
clothing = [x for x in l if x[0] == 'clothing']
```

You can even sort them in place

```
>>> music.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
<<< [('music', '400', 'url'), ('music', '350', 'url'), ('music', '300', 'url')]
```

I'd just use a dict, personally. Simple data structures are best.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in l:
    d[x[0]].append(x[1:])
```

Which would give you something like:

```
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
...:     print k, v
...:
...:
movie [('400', 'url'), ('1000', 'url')]
clothing [('250', 'url')]
music [('300', 'url'), ('350', 'url'), ('400', 'url')]
```

But then that's my solution for everything so maybe I need to branch out a little.

Comment: your last solution still needs sorting for my purposes.  it appears in my tests that if I just sort the list first (on the second element (as an int not a string)) using: l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True), then use your dict method that it comes out correct in all of the subsequent dicts.  am i missing something with that that might trip me up?

Comment: Sure you can do that, each key is a list so you can just sort them in-place later too: `d['movie'].sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`, or: `for k in d: d[k].sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: But yeah, sorting the list up-front is probably the best solution, if you use the dict approach, saves you from sorting multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import itertools
import operator

sorted_l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1])), reverse=True)

print [list(g[1]) for g in itertools.groupby(sorted_l, key=operator.itemgetter(0))]
```

Output :

```
[[('music', '400', 'url'), ('music', '350', 'url'), ('music', '300', 'url')],
 [('movie', '1000', 'url'), ('movie', '400', 'url')],
 [('clothing', '250', 'url')]]
```

Comment: I think that is not working correctly since movies are not sorted

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in a case like this is a dictionary of lists.

```
things = {}

for tuple in all_tuples:
    key = tuple[0]
    if not key in things:
        things[key] = [] # Initialize empty list
    things[key].append(tuple)
```

Then you can iterate through "things" using things.keys() or things.values()

E.g.

```
things["music"] = [('music','400','url'),('music','350','url'),('music','300','url')]
```